# FindFirstChangeNotification() triggers for changes in subdirectories although wWatchSubtree is set to FALSE

Tags: winapi

I'm trying to listen for notifications on changes in a directory like so:

```
handle = FindFirstChangeNotification("D:/Test", FALSE, FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME|FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_DIR_NAME|FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_ATTRIBUTES|FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_SIZE|FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE);
```

This works as expected but there's one strange thing: When I copy a file to the directory `D:/Test/SubDir` I'm also getting notified. This is confusing me because the documentation of `wWatchSubtree` says:

> If this parameter is TRUE, the function monitors the directory tree
>   rooted at the specified directory; if it is FALSE, it monitors only
>   the specified directory.

As you can see, I'm setting it to FALSE but still I'm getting notified if things change in `D:/Test/SubDir` although I only want to be notified about changes in `D:/Test`. Is this supposed to behave this way and if it is, how can I change this to only get notified about changes in `D:/Test` and not in `D:/Test/SubDir` and other subdirectories?

Comment: If you copy a file to `D:/Test/SubDir`, the last-modified timestamp of `D:/Test/SubDir` (the directory) is updated. That's an entry you are monitoring, because it is a direct child of `D:/Test`. If you were to copy a file to `D:/Test/SubDir/SubDir`, you would not receive a notification.

Comment: Obvious, right. For some reason I didn't think of this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for the record and to mark this question as answered, IInspectable solved it in the comments above:

> If you copy a file to D:/Test/SubDir, the last-modified timestamp of
>   D:/Test/SubDir (the directory) is updated. That's an entry you are
>   monitoring, because it is a direct child of D:/Test. If you were to
>   copy a file to D:/Test/SubDir/SubDir, you would not receive a
>   notification.